# Change Y Axis Value to Integer (no decimal values) in AmCharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have a chart in AmCharts that reflects integer values; as such I want the value in the Y Axis to also be integers however they are showing up as floating point. I have read through documentation and found reference to: numberFormatter with the following syntax:

```
chart.numberFormatter = { precision:-1,decimalSeparator:".",thousandsSeparator:"," };
```

Changing the precision does not seem to have an impact. I've seen suggestions at setting it to 0 would work for removing the value after the decimal but it does not. I have also read that setting precision to -1 inhibits rounding which confuses me as to what precision is used for.

I am using **AmCharts version 2.9.3**. I have found that there is a bug where numberFormatter is ignored in this version (pre 2.11) when usePrefixes was set to true however that is not the case.

I have found references to a parameter called: `digits_after_decimal`

However the references I found were for much older versions of AmCharts and the reference was for this parameter in a config file; and I do not see a reference for this in my version.

I have done quite a bit of research and am looking for any pointers as to what I am doing wrong as I know this is simply a misunderstanding of the API. I have also been toying with a JSFiddle example from AmCharts site:

http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/zu9nW/

Answer (score 25):

For amCharts v4 it will be:

`valueAxis.maxPrecision = 0;`

Comment: Worked for me in amcharts 4

Answer (score 10):

I have found a solution. There are custom sections for updating qualities of both the y and x axis; in this case for the y axis, adding the following will represent only integers for the value column which on my graph was the y axis.

`var valuesAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();`

`valuesAxis.integersOnly = true;`

Comment: chart.addValueAxis(valuesAxis);

Answer (score 0):

In my code for the `valueAxes` object I have added `integersOnly` property `true`. It is working fine for me.

```
"valueAxes": [ {
    "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "gridAlpha": 0.2,
    "dashLength": 0,
    "title": "Response Count",
    "autoGridCount": false,
    "gridCount": 5,
    'integersOnly':true
  },
],
```